# Scraping video links from a dynamic video player web page in Android application

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, mp4

I am developing an application whose purpose is to download MP4 videos from an online video player. The user opens up the video player and my application should download the video which the user specifies.

The video player shows dynamic content and by that I mean, there is no fixed number of videos that it can show. Sometimes It shows four videos and sometimes even fifty. There is a next and previous button on the video player. These buttons skip or return back to the video currently loaded by the video player.

Currently, I am scraping the web-page of the video player and the link of the MP4 video currently played is accessible from the web page's HTML source code. What I want is that my application should retrieve all of these links in one go which is only possible by clicking next button on the video player and scraping the link from HTML code until there are no videos left to be displayed.

Can someone suggest any technique to automate this in code such that my application automatically scrapes all of these links by clicking the next button? Is there anything like Selenium Web Driver for Android applications that can automate this or another technique to do this elegantly and fast?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a crawler like [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) and look for links in `<a>` and accessing the pages, the hard part is keep the accessed links to not get in a loop, and you can find if element is a video by it's format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did some research on JSoup and it can be used to scrap the video links. However, as mentioned in the question, the real problem is how to get all the video links loaded by the web-player in one go. I cannot manually press next each time to update the video links in the web-page's HTML.